# COMBOBOX SELECT ANIDADO GUARDAR VALOR Y NO ID

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

Hola Estoy trabajando en un option select anidado de 3 niveles, funciona correctamente al desplegar cada select el unico detalle es que no me guarda los valores ejemplo (activo, marca, modelo) sino los ID (1,2,2) Espero su ayuda gracias

```
CODIGO HTML

<div>Select Descripcion : <select name="cbx_activo" id="cbx_activo">
            <option value="0">Elige una opcion</option>
            <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id_activo']; ?>"><?php echo $row['activo']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select></div>
        
        <br />
        
        <div>Select Marca : <select name="cbx_marca" id="cbx_marca"></select></div>
        
        <br />
        
        <div>Select Modelo : <select name="cbx_modelo" id="cbx_modelo"></select></div>


    CODIGO JAVASCRIPT
```

/* ====== Select anidado activo-marca ======*/
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#cbx_activo").change(function () {

                    $('#cbx_modelo').find('option').remove().end().append('Elige una opcion').val('whatever');

                    $("#cbx_activo option:selected").each(function () {
                        id_activo = $(this).val();
                        $.post("includes/GetMarca.php", { id_activo: id_activo }, function(data){
                            $("#cbx_marca").html(data);
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });

            /* ====== Select anidado marca-modelo ======*/
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#cbx_marca").change(function () {
                    $("#cbx_marca option:selected").each(function () {
                        id_marca = $(this).val();
                        $.post("includes/GetModelo.php", { id_marca: id_marca }, function(data){
                            $("#cbx_modelo").html(data);
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });

```
ARCHIVO GetMarca.php

require ('../conexion.php');

$id_activo = $_POST['id_activo'];

$queryM = "SELECT id_marca, marca FROM marca WHERE id_activo = '$id_activo' ORDER BY marca";
$resultadoM = $mysqli->query($queryM);

$html= "<option value='0'>Elige una opcion</option>";

while($rowM = $resultadoM->fetch_assoc())
{
    $html.= "<option value='".$rowM['id_marca']."'>".$rowM['marca']."</option>";
}

echo $html;





ARCHIVO GetModelo.php

require ('../conexion.php');

$id_marca = $_POST['id_marca'];

$query = "SELECT id_modelo, modelo FROM modelo WHERE id_marca = '$id_marca' ORDER BY modelo";
$resultado=$mysqli->query($query);

$html= "<option value='0'>Elige una opcion</option>";

while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
{
    $html.= "<option value='".$row['id_modelo']."'>".$row['modelo']."</option>";
}
echo $html;


Ese es mi codigo fuente a la hora de guardar no guardar los value sino el id 1, 1, 2.

AQUI DEJO EL CODIGO FUENTE COMPLETO CON BASE DE DATOS PARA MEJOR APOYO. GRACIAS
```

https://mega.nz/file/H3QEFC5B#JP8Sud5Rt3HCba2HSIMzt-98ykzcenTQc2Kuy0u_CM0

Comment: El código mínimo para entender tu problema va aqui en la pregunta, por otro lado el código va como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Entiendo, pero deje un enlance en mega con los codigos y base de datos para una mejor ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]esto es lo que hice basicamente tu ponias el id en el value de los option, entonces tiene que ir en su respectivo id jeje cargare imagenes o si me proporcionas tu correo te puedo pasar las modificaciones que hice sin embargo no se si asi lo quieras, es lo que yo entendi de lo que publicaste

```
<?php while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                <option id="<?php echo $row['id_activo']; ?>" value="<?php echo 
 $row['activo']; ?>"><?php echo $row['activo']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>




 $("#cbx_activo option:selected").each(function() {
                id_activo = this.id
                $.post("includes/GetMarca.php", {
                    id_activo: id_activo

                }, function(data) {
                    $("#cbx_marca").html(data);
                });

            })


$("#cbx_marca").change(function() {
            $("#cbx_marca option:selected").each(function() {
                id_marca = this.id

                alert(id_marca);
                $.post("includes/GetModelo.php", {
                    id_marca: id_marca
                }, function(data) {
                    $("#cbx_modelo").html(data);
                });
            });
        })








while ($rowM = $resultadoM->fetch_assoc()) {
$html .= "<option id=" . $rowM['id_marca'] . " value='" . $rowM['marca'] . "'>" .
```

``$rowM['marca'] . "";
}

son las modificaciones que hice,  perdon por el desorden soy nuevo y no se como acomodar las cosas todavia jeje , pero como te digo si tienes correo te lo mando si no le entiendes

Comment: Ok probare este codigo, si puedes porfavor sube las imagenes.. y no se, si pueda publicar mi correo por aca, o si incumplo con las politicas soy nuevo.

Comment: jaja yo tambien soy nuevo asi que la verdad no se pero publicare imagenes

Comment: por favor.. o subelo a un enlace. Agradecido

Comment: no tengo mega o fire, pero ya subi la imagen, espero se entienda el cambio es sencillo

Comment: Probando codigo.

Comment: Por favor evitemos responder con fragmentos de códigos en imágenes salvo que sea estrictamente necesario

Comment: no me ha funcionado, lo hice tal cual y no se despliega los select

Comment: a mi si me ha funcionado, se me hace raro, si quieres poner el correo y te lo paso tal cual como lo tengo

Comment: acabo de crear una cuenta espero lo puedas descargar, cambia la conexion puesto que lo tengo con contraseña https://mega.nz/file/eLA2ACIR#Lij8MfT4sjT-jRqY5TkYcv6j0e3Tb83q7Jlbs6SAZug

Comment: Excelente mi amigo, quedo a la perfeccion y como yo queria..! Buen apoyo

Comment: saludos .. y para modificar? que se traiga lo registrado en la base? xq no me aparece